# Pundit: user_signed_in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, pundit

I am using Pundit to deal with authorizations. 
I want my user's profiles to be visible by everyone so in my user_policy.rb, I have:

```
 def show?
    true  # Anyone can view a show
  end
```

In my users/show.html.erb, the "edit profile" button is displayed only if:

```
<% if policy(@user).update? %>
  <!--  show edit button  -->
<% end %>
```

The issue is that when I try to access a profile and I'm not logged in, Pundit is looking for a "user":

```
def update?
  record == user || user.admin == true # Only user creator can update it
end
```

I have an error saying that user is nil so admin is undefined. 
I wanted to do this:

```
def update?
  if user_signed_in?
    record == user || user.admin == true # Only user creator can update it
  else
    false
  end
end
```

but user_signed_in? is a devise helper, not accessible in Pundit.
Is there an equivalent I could use or a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just check that user variable exists first?

```
def update?
  user && (record == user || user.admin == true) # Only user creator can update it
end
```

Answer (score 3):

As Richard said, you should verify that there is a user first, and if he is the owner or an admin. I like to read it this way:

```
  def update?
    user.present? && (is_owner? || is_admin?)
  end

private

 def is_owner?
   record.user == user
 end
 def is_admin?
   user.admin #In your case user.admin is simple enough so you don't need that, but sometimes it's not.
 end
```

Comment: user.present will also handle the case of a registered but unconfirmed user  - a devise functionality.  Quite convenient